# Still not very sure what this xpath <*[local-name()=\'date\']/@*[name()=\'today\' or name()=\'tomorrow\']> can find

Tags: xml, xpath

Please pardon me for asking this stupid question, but I don't quite understand what 
 `/@*[name()=\'today\' or name()=\'tomorrow\']` means in the below xpath

`<*[local-name()=\'date\']/@*[name()=\'today\' or name()=\'tomorrow\']>`

I'm confused about the asterisks before `name()=`. I know that the asterisk before local name is to specify the prefix/namespace, but what does the asterisk do in front of the attributes?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `/@*` means *any attribute*. Predicate `[name()=\'today\' or name()=\'tomorrow\']` tells you that not actually *any*, but only attributes `@today` or `@tomorrow`

Comment: Thanks, @Andersson, if I understand you correctly, the xpath means local name `date`'s attribute `today` and `tomorrow`. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Then next question is, since this xpath only grabs `today` and `tomorrow`, why don't we write it as `@[name()='today' or name()='tomorrow'`? Why the asterisk?

Comment: XPath should return you values of `@today` or/and `@tomorrow` attributes from matched `date` node. It's hard to tell you *why*- you should specify node name (or asterisk)- it's just correct syntax :) If you don't want to use asterisk, you can try `/*[local-name()=\'date\']/(@today | @tomorrow)`

Comment: Thank you so much! Apparently, I asked the right person! Can I ask one last question? So for this `//h/@*[local-name()='include']|`, why the attribute has a `local-name`, unless the attribute may also has a prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `@*[name()=\'today\' or name()=\'tomorrow\']` selects all attributes whose name() is either 'today' or 'tomorrow'. The name() of an attribute is NAME for an unprefixed attribute, or PREFIX:NAME for a prefixed attribute; this expression therefore tests whether there is a no-namespace attribute called 'today' or 'tomorrow': in XPath 2.0 you would be better off writing this as `(@today|@tomorrow)`.

When applied to attributes, the difference between `name()="X"` and `local-name()="X"` is that the first case will only match a no-namespace attribute, whereas the second case will also match, for example, an attribute named P:X.

Comment: Thank you again @michaelKay! It's clear to me now. Appreciate the help!